# Dot in place of prime to denote differentiation

Tags: custom-notation

To denote differentiation with respect to time I wish to use overhead dots rather than primes, so that differential expressions will look somewhat like this:

$\quad \quad$ `DSolve`$[\ddot y[t] + \dot y[t]==0,\,\dot y[0]==0,\,y[0]==1,\,y,\,t]$

I would like to use this notation after the usual $y''[x]$ prime has been reserved to denote differentiation with respect to distance and because I also want to avoid using `D`, `Dt`.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I am missing something. Can you please give the lines that I can copy/paste so it appears as above on the last line with dots above the letters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
OverDot[f_, n_Integer] := Derivative[n][f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It really only works for `.` and `\[DoubleDot]`.

To keep the output from displaying as `y'[x]`, etc., you could define

```
MakeBoxes[Derivative[n_Integer][f_], form_] /; 1 <= n <= 2 := 
 ToBoxes[HoldForm[OverDot[f, n]], form]
```